# Representing matrix with TikZ - minimum size issue

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to represent a matrix elements with circles with Tikz.

Matrix in question is the CKM matrix [image]

My current code is

```
\[V=\begin{pmatrix}   \tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\node[circle,fill=black,minimum size=1.948em] (a) {};} 
& \tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\node[circle,fill=black,minimum size=0.45em] (b) {};} 
& \tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\node[circle,fill=black,minimum size=0.006em] (c) {};} \\

\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\node[circle,fill=black,minimum size=0.45em] (d) {};} 
& \tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\node[circle,fill=black,minimum size=1.946em] (e) {};} 
& \tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\node[circle,fill=black,minimum size=0.082em] (f) {};} \\

\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\node[circle,fill=black,minimum size=0.006em] (g) {};} 
& \tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\node[circle,fill=black,minimum size=0.082em] (h) {};} 
& \tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\node[circle,fill=black,minimum size=1.998em] (i) {};} \\ \end{pmatrix} \]
```

The problem is, circles of size 0.45 are printed as the same size as the circles of size 0.006. This leads me to believe there is a "minimum size". How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe adding `inner sep=0pt` can help?

Comment: @JasperHabicht It helps! comment as an answer so I cna upvote you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand what you try to achieve, but you should probably add `inner sep=0pt` as option to the `\node`s. I would also define a custom macro to make repetitive code easier to handle:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}

\newcommand{\mycircle}[2]{%
    \tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{ 
        \node[circle, fill=black, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=#2] (#1) {};
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\[V=\begin{pmatrix}
\mycircle{a}{1.948em} &
\mycircle{b}{0.45em} &
\mycircle{c}{0.006em} \\

\mycircle{d}{0.45em} &
\mycircle{e}{1.946em} &
\mycircle{f}{0.082em} \\

\mycircle{g}{0.006em} &
\mycircle{h}{0.082em} &
\mycircle{i}{1.998em} \\
\end{pmatrix} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]